Optimizing Batch Inserts for Improved Efficiency in Flask SQLAlchemy
I am trying to insert 60 to 70 rows at once in a SQL Server table. Currently, I have a function to do it but it is taking almost 15 seconds to complete the task. It would not be a problem if it was just that, but I have to do this up to 40 times. The whole process ends up taking around 6 to 12 minutes.
This is my current function (the one that takes 15 seconds each time it runs):
def delete_insert_data(df):
    months_to_erase = list(set(df['month']))
    year_to_erase = list(set(df['year']))[0]
    product_code = df.iloc[0,0]

    for month_to_erase in months_to_erase:
        db.session.execute(delete(finance_products).where(
            finance_products.product_code  == product_code ,
            finance_products.year == year_to_erase,
            finance_products.month == month_to_erase
        ))

    records_to_insert = df.to_dict(orient='records')

    db.session.execute(insert(finance_products), records_to_insert)
    db.session.commit()

Is there any way I can insert this data faster?
I have tried inserting the data row by row, with the db.session.add() and it was worse. The
bulk_insert_mappings() was basically the same and I also tried "cleaning" the session after the commit with db.session.expunge_all(), but it was also the same.

that delete in the for loop could use some optimizations, what about db.session.execute(delete(finance_products).where(finance_products.product_code == product_code, finance_products.year == year_to_erase, finance_products.month.in_(months_to_erase))) instead of that for loop, does it do anything better in terms of execution?

Hey @python_user, thanks for the suggestion. It really makes it more efficient, but I'm afraid what's taking so long is the "db.session.execute(insert(finance_products), records_to_insert)". Unfortunately, the alteration didn't have a meaningful impact.
